# Where is size of password (for command passwd) set?

Tags: shell, passwords, command

There is header file pwd.h for programming language C.
I want to know if this is the only file, where size of a password is set?
Do I have to edit files of command mcrypt too and the files of shadow (command passwd) too - when I want to change the size of a password?

As I read by the source files, is the password currently in Linux set to maximum of 513 characters (in file extra.h of mcrypt sources). When I want to change to a bigger size, which files would I have to edit ?

The fear is that quantum computers are able to crack 513 characters without too much effort.

The idea is to do this following:

first step: generate an individually cipher-salad file in *.txt format to save it on usb-stick with a size of up to 1 GB.

second step: to type command in login window of Linux (gdm or lightdm) with which you start a shell-script on your machine. The shell-script is stored for example in /home - the command could look like this:

```
> exec 3</home/linux/name-of-shell.sh
```

third step is that this name-of-shell-script is then started :

```
#! /bin/bash

while read file /media/usb/cipher-salad.txt
do
    passwd | stdin
done < /media/usb/cipher-salad.txt`
```

Then password would be read in from usb-stick as file up to size of 1 GB.

Up to today the sources for passwd are declared with char for size up to 513 ciphers in password.

When declared with int the size up to 4 GB would be possible, but sufficient would be at first a size up to 1 GB.

Disadvantage of this idea is, that you can use usb-stick only off-line from internet (otherwise there would be danger that it could be copied online). One would only need the usb-stick in machine, when password is needed and then plug-out usb-stick after process with password is settled.

I think, this could be a little revolution for linux-community and an earth-quake for security, when global mass-surveillance is hold up.

Comment: Now we are talking. You try to use something, that is not indent. (it would be like using a spoon, to slice a bread. No, just.. no!).
What I would suggest you is using 2FA (two factor-authentication). There are some tools that will accomplish that (e.g. https://github.com/CERN-CERT/pam_2fa). Elsewise I would suggest using ssh and keyfiles? That could work as well.

Comment: @hellow - I admit that my idea is somewhat crazy, but this would work when all would be declared with int. Thanks for your FA2 hint and for listening.

Comment: @hellow - where is source code of pwd.h ? - I think with switch case built in , this would work...

Comment: No... Don't! Don't invent something on your own. I beg you, use existing tools, do not invent the wheel again. Use PAM as an interface, but do not modify system headers.

Comment: @hellow - okay. Then I look at PAM and 2FA. Don't worry.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In short, **don't**.

In long, you may able to edit those files, but then you have to recompile all of the applications, which rely on `pwd.h`. This is not feasible and not what you want. You may explain, why 512 chars is not enough for your purpose, and we may can suggest a solution for this (by using a *key derivation function* or similar).

Comment: how should I reply to you - comment-size is too small for full answer ... - well, I edit my question then and complet it.

Comment: How are 600 characters too less for a comment? Oo